# What are alternatives to --no-commit-hooks and --no-git-tag-version in yarn v4

Tags: continuous-integration, yarn-v4

I'm migrating from the classic yarn to version 4 and encountered an issue with my version bump CI job since the `--no-commit-hooks` and `--no-git-tag-version` flags are not there anymore with the modern yarn versions.

This is a part of the Gitlab CI job I use for bumping the version (using the classic yarn):

```yaml
  script:
    - ... some preparing scripts
    - git tag -a v$APP_VERSION -m "v$APP_VERSION"
    - yarn version --patch --no-commit-hooks --no-git-tag-version
    - git pull origin $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -X theirs --no-commit && git commit -a -m "chore(release): v$APP_VERSION"
    - git push -o ci.skip --tags origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

To break it down:

- We're skipping the git hooks (to avoid issues with Husky and other precommit tools)
- we're creating the tag with the **existing** (pre-version) package.json version
- and we're modifying the commit message to be in the expected format.

What would be the alternative way of doing this with yarn v4?

I've been going through the yarn documentation, but the [`version` CLI docs](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/version) are showing that the command has only some basic configuration options. I've also opened [an discussion](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/discussions/6028) in the berry repo, but no responses so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like I've been looking for replacements for the above hooks but haven't tested the behavior of the `yarn version`. `yarn version` bumps the version but doesn't create a tag or commit, so that's nice. It also runs the `yarn install`, which is not nice. In the end, the following piece of code can replace the configuration I've been using for yarn classic:

```yaml
  script:
    - ... some preparing scripts
    - git tag -a v$APP_VERSION -m "v$APP_VERSION"
    - yarn version patch
    - git pull origin $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -X theirs --no-commit && git commit -a -m "chore(release): v$APP_VERSION" --no-verify
    - git push -o ci.skip --tags origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --no-verify
```

Using `no-verify` to skip running git hooks. It would be nice to prevent `yarn install` as well, but I couldn't find a solution for that, and there is an unanswered discussion for the same issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/discussions/4551.